# Plugin strip ~ How to exclude a specific file whose extension was included generally?

Tags: rollupjs

I'm using the rollup plugin strip to exclude the console.logs in the production built with following settings

```
plugins: [
                strip({
                    include: ['**/*.(js|svelte)'],
                    labels: ['dev'],
                    functions: ['console.log'],
                })
            ]
```

I now have the situation that I would like to keep one special log in production. So I created a function in a new file `logInProduction.js`

```
export function logInProduction(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    throw new Error('PRODUCTION')
}
```

and added the file to the plugin options by adding this line

```
exclude: ['logInProduction.js'],
```

But when calling the function, the error is thrown, so the function was called, but the log before doesn't appear.

Is this because the .js ending is generally included before so the specific exclusion doen't have any effect? Is it possible to do this?

Or is there another maybe better way to keep one specific console.log?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that the filename was missing the directory, so

```
exclude: ['src/utils/logInProduction.js'],
```

or

```
exclude: ['**/logInProduction.js'],
```

does work